# Fragment not calling onClick

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've got a Fragment implementing onClickListener. What I have is a custom dialer which must show on the edittext the introduced number. But it doesn't show anything.

This is the Fragment:

PhoneView.java

```
public class PhoneView extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener, OnClickListener {
...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_view, null);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        setupTabs();
        return mRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        ...

        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.one);
        EditText numTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.digits);
        ...

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);  //UPDATED - ADDED
        ...
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){        
            case R.id.one:
               numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"1");
               break;
            ...
```

Comment: What are you doing in the onCreateView method ?

Comment: where is setOnclickListener(this); statement in the above code , as it should be there where the click event has to be genereated from

Comment: Added on the code, updated the post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to call onClickListener on fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928390/correct-way-to-call-onclicklistener-on-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)` of the view you want to react on the click event

Comment: Wehre do I call this? and what view do you refer to? the layout or a ImageButton?

Comment: for instance button1.setOnClickListener(this); (after findViewById)

Comment: I mean that the editText doesn't show the numbers, so there must be something more worng. I've updated the post adding some more code

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity class, you need to define your `Phoneview` as you ClickListener to the button or another "view"

Suppose in your activity class, u have a button named `deleteButton`, and if u want to register a listener for this button... This is how you would do it.

```
private Button deleteButton= null;
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(PhoneView);
```

Comment: Could be this done directly on the fragment? I've updated the post adding some more code. I think this way should work but doesn't update the edittext