# Correct way to call onClickListener on fragments

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm developing an app that contains a custom dialer fragment. The functionality of this fragment should be the same as the stock dialer. When I push a button, that number appears on the editText window, as simple as that.

But, it doesn't appear no number on the editText. I first tried this using Activities instead of fragments and it worked. Now I've been forced to change the activities to fragments, and I've been adapting the code to the fragments eviroment, but this functionality doesn't work.

This is the `PhoneView` fragment:

```
public class PhoneView extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener, OnClickListener {

    ImageButton dialBtn;
    ImageButton clearBtn;
    EditText numTxt;
    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    ImageButton button3;
    ImageButton button4;
    ImageButton button5;
    ImageButton button6;
    ImageButton button7;
    ImageButton button8;
    ImageButton button9;
    ImageButton button0;
    ImageButton buttonstar;
    ImageButton buttonpound;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_view, null);

        dialBtn = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.dialButton);
        clearBtn = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        numTxt = (EditText) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.digits);
        button1 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.one);
        button2 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.two);
        button3 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.three);
        button4 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.four);
        button5 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.five);
        button6 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.six);
        button7 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.seven);
        button8 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.eight);
        button9 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.nine);
        button0 = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.zero);
        buttonstar = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.star);
        buttonpound = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.pound);

        dialBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        button0.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonstar.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonpound.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.dialButton:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + numTxt.getText())));
                break;
            case R.id.deleteButton:
                String contents = numTxt.getText().toString();
                if (contents.length() > 0) {
                    numTxt.setText(contents.substring(0, contents.length()-1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.one:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"1");
                break;
            case R.id.two:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"2");
                break;
            case R.id.three:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"3");
                break;
            case R.id.four:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"4");
                break;
            case R.id.five:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"5");
                break;
            case R.id.six:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"6");
                break;
            case R.id.seven:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"7");
                break;
            case R.id.eight:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"8");
                break;
            case R.id.nine:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"9");
                break;
            case R.id.zero:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"0");
                break;
            case R.id.star:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"*");
                break;
            case R.id.pound:
                numTxt.setText(numTxt.getText()+"#");
                break;
        }
```

Have to say that for example the dial button works, what doesn't work is the showing of the pressed numbers on the edittext. Could be this related to any restriction or special functionality of the fragments?

**UPDATED -> Added more code above, and following the xml**

**phone_view.xml**

```
<!-- Layout for the dialer -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Right_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialpad_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#000000" > 

    <!-- Text field above the keypad where the digits are displayed -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/digits_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_digits"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digits"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/DialtactsDigitsTextAppearance"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:inputType="none" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="56dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_delete_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dial_action_delete" 
            android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The dialpad itself -->
    <include layout="@layout/dialpad" />

    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
       android:background="#66000000"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_additional_buttons"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dialButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_call"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_dial_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dial_action_call" />

</FrameLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

**dialpad.xml**

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialpad"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0px"
android:layout_weight="@integer/dialpad_layout_weight_dialpad"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialpad_vertical_margin"
android:paddingStart="5dip"
android:paddingEnd="5dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:background="@drawable/dialpad_background"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1" >
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/one" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_1_no_vm_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/two" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_2_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_two" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/three" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_3_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_three" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/four" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_4_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_four" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/five" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_5_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_five" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/six" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_6_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_six" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/seven" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_7_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_seven" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/eight" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_8_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_eight" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/nine" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_9_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_nine" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/star" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_star_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_star" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/zero" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_0_no_plus_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_zero" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/pound" 
        style="@style/DialpadButtonStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/dial_num_pound_wht"
        android:background="@drawable/dialbtn_push"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_pound" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: you posted the same question yesterday

Comment: Yes, I've been looking for the solution but nothing... I've tryed to change some things, this is way I created a new question. The declaration is a bit diferent than the way I had yesterday.

Comment: @masmic_87 if it s duplicate you can always edit your question. and you don't get a solution you can offer a bounty

Comment: I'll delete yesterday's question then, I think this has more code and the question is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `numTxt` as a class member. You have

```
EditText numTxt = (EditText) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.digits);
// local to onCreateView
```

Change to

```
EditText numTxt;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_view, null);

        ImageButton dialBtn = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.dialButton);
        ImageButton clearBtn = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        numTxt = (EditText) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.digits);
```

Edit : To the updated question

As i said in the comments i see nothing wrong with the code posted.

Since you said you can't set text to editext, i just ran your code. For testing purpose i set the launcher icon as background to `ImageButton`. I modified the ui for testing purpose.

But the logic is the same you used

[image]

Comment: Updated that way but still doesn't work. Is there any issue on using the editText with fragments? I'm investing a bit and it seems that this thing of updating an edittext dinamically with fragments causes this kind of issues.. but, how to selve it?

Comment: @masmic_87 check if your edittext is properly initialized. Not the fault of fragment

Comment: Yes, it is properly initialized. I getting crazy looking for the cause that this doesn't work... Could be something reffering to the setText()??

Comment: @masmic_87 from the code posted i don't see any thing wrong. post your full code. and what is entered in edittext?

Comment: Updated the post. I've added full declarations on the original question. I don't have more code there. And added the layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41020/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-masmic-87)

Comment: @masmic_87 i don't see a problem i ran your code and it works fine.

Comment: @masmic_87 if you want i can post a snap shot of running the same on my emulator. i see nothing wrong with the code works for me

Comment: @masmic_87 with the code you posted i see nothing wrong. i can't see any mistake.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why doesn't work for me, but I'm going crazy! xD Thanks for your help. I'll invest a little more to see if I can find the cause of this. If I find something I'll post a new question

Comment: You won't believe this... I find whats happening! The text has the same color as the background... that's why I don't see it...LOL

Comment: @masmic_87 wow. thats why it worked for me if i changed the ui. Next time set a text to edittext in xml and check in graphical editor if its visible.