# How to open a browser through a Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have tried following 2 different links with no success.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536165/how-can-imageview-link-to-web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505788/how-to-open-default-browser/3505804#3505804)

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505788/how-to-open-default-browser/3505804#3505804

I do apologize if this is a simple fix but i'm that nooby and getting frustrated because according to those examples it should work.

Here is my Xml layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_about"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.11"
            android:src="@drawable/web_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/info_about_us"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <!-- Contact Us -->

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_icon"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_indicator"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icon"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/title_contact_us"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/info_contact_us"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_indicator"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/devider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/grey" />
    </RelativeLayout>


      <!-- Facebook -->

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50sp"
         android:clickable="true" 
         android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
             android:layout_width="40sp"
             android:layout_height="40sp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_name1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebook_icon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebook_icon"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook_icon"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/title_facebook"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_content1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name1"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name1"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/info_facebook"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="13sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_indicator1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="@color/grey" />
     </RelativeLayout>


      <!-- Google Plus -->

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50sp"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/google_icon"
             android:layout_width="40sp"
             android:layout_height="40sp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_googleplus" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_name2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/google_icon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/google_icon"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/google_icon"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/title_google_plus"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_content2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name2"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name2"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name2"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/info_google_plus"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="13sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_indicator2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="@color/grey" />
     </RelativeLayout>

       <!-- Website -->

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50sp"
         android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/website_icon"
             android:layout_width="40sp"
             android:layout_height="40sp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_website" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_name3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/website_icon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_indicator3"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/website_icon"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/title_website"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_content3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name3"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name3"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name3"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/info_website"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="13sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_indicator3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="@color/grey" />
     </RelativeLayout>

      <!-- Rate Us -->

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50sp"
         android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/rate_icon"
             android:layout_width="40sp"
             android:layout_height="40sp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_rate_me" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_name4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rate_icon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_indicator4"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rate_icon"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/title_rate_us"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_content4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name4"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name4"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name4"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/info_rate_us"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="13sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_indicator4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="@color/grey" />
     </RelativeLayout>

      <!-- More Apps -->

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50sp"
         android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/apps_icon"
             android:layout_width="40sp"
             android:layout_height="40sp"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/icon_more_app" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_name5"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/apps_icon"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_indicator5"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/apps_icon"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/title_more_app"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tv_content5"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_name5"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_name5"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name5"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="@string/info_more_app"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textSize="13sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_indicator5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:background="@color/grey" />
     </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now my Fragment.java

```
package com.wny.wecare.fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.wny.wecare.R;


public class AboutUsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

public static final String TAG = AboutUsFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    private View mRootView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
        return mRootView;

    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        ImageView Img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.img_indicator);
        Img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com")));
                    }
                });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Hours of reading i finally solved this issue.
Thanks to this link [Correct way to call onClickListener on fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928390/correct-way-to-call-onclicklistener-on-fragments?rq=1)

Thank You all for your help, very appreciated.

Here is my full AboutUsFragment.Java

```
package com.wny.wecare.fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.wny.wecare.MainActivity;
import com.wny.wecare.R;


public class AboutUsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView Contact;
    ImageView Facebook;
    ImageView Google;
    ImageView Website;
    ImageView Rate;
    ImageView Apps;

    public static final String TAG = AboutUsFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    private View mRootView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, null);

        Contact = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.contact_icon);
        Contact.setOnClickListener(this);

        Facebook = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon);
        Facebook.setOnClickListener(this);

        Google = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.google_icon);
        Google.setOnClickListener(this);

        Website = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.website_icon);
        Website.setOnClickListener(this);

        Rate = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.rate_icon);
        Rate.setOnClickListener(this);

        Apps = (ImageView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.apps_icon);
        Apps.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mRoot;

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.contact_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mailto:infinitycodeservices@gmail.com")));
            break;

        case R.id.facebook_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com/infinitycodeservices")));
            break;

        case R.id.google_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/105796163192090141980/")));
            break;

        case R.id.website_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com")));
            break;

        case R.id.rate_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=InfinityCodeServices")));
            break;

        case R.id.apps_icon:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=InfinityCodeServices")));
            break;  

        }

    }





    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        Intent intent;
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            String cameback="CameBack";
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Comingback", cameback);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this rather bro

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView Img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.img_indicator);
    if(v == img)
        Context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com"))); //context stands 4 ur activity
}
```

Edit 1: i change the `intent` to `Intent` this was the reason for the earlier variable error..

> so retry & seee

let me know if it works.. <strike>im feeling i left something</strike>.

Comment: I tried your method and i have received this error "intent cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: checki if you **have imported intent** `import android.content.Intent;`.. that might be the problem, sir..

Comment: im very sorry sir, please check my edit, it was a typo of the intent.. @user3802844

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, your `public void onClick(View v)` not called you just declare but don't set Listener,then when you set listener to ImageView on `onClick()` that never call too.

I think you should `setListener()` in `onCreateView()` by using anonymous inner class like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    ImageView Img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.img_indicator);
    Img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com")));
        }
    });

    return mRootView;
}
```

or If you still use implement `View.OnClickListener()` use this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);
    ImageView Img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.img_indicator);
    Img.setOnClickListener(this);

    return mRootView;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com")));
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You are in a Fragment so I think you should invoke startActivity() method using:

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://infinitycodeservices.com")));
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and no response or error.

Comment: Maybe i did not understand your task but if you want open **default browser** from a fragment this is the correct solution. otherwise if you want open web pages within your app you should use a **WebView**.